# Condional binding for Html.Textbox In MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do i bind the data for html.textbox based on some condition in view like below.

If long_variable is 0, i want to assign empty to the `Html.TextBox`, else the value which is in long_variable.

```
Html.TextBox("long_variable", "", new { @class = "short"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value of this property and set the value of textbox conditionally.

If it is a local variable in your view,

```
@{
   long myLong = 0;

   @Html.TextBox("long_variable", myLong != 0 ? myLong.ToString() : "",
                                                                    new {@class = "short"});
}
```

If it is a property of your view model,

```
@Html.TextBox("long_variable",Model.MyLong != 0 ? Model.MyLong.ToString() : "",
                                                                    new {@class = "short"})
```